# hibernate_sequence not found error

Tags: hibernate, sequence

I did the above mentioned changes of changing sequence to sequence_name as well as changing the `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` to `"false"`. Still I get the same error that

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
>   Schema-validation: missing sequence [hibernate_sequence]

This was all working with hibernate3 and upgrading to 5.0.12 is causing this error with postgresql

Can someone please help out as I am stuck for more than a day now.

Thanks Surya

Comment: Where did you mention?!

Comment: please add your entity and exception trace here.

Comment: ultimately had to create a dummy sequence. None of the other solutions worked,